# Need a log based replication / CDC solution to publish postgres to oracle subscribers

Tags: postgresql, replication

We have a moderately large postgres 9.1 db that is currently 3TB and will likely grow much larger over the next couple of years. we need a reliable and fast solution for moving this data into either oracle 11G or sql server 2012 databases. we need a log based solution like replication or CDC with a minimal foot print of the postgres server and not looking for a  code based ETL solution like SSIS or SAP Data Services.

It should also be able to effectively handle blob / spatial data that is stored in postgres

Comment: Is there a particular reason you *need* to move the data out (as opposed to querying your Postgres server from the other databases)? You could theoretically do CDC with triggers, or write something to process archived WAL segments, but both of those strike me as particularly nasty solutions...

Comment: Do you want to do a one time move and then use the new solution, or is this an ongoing process?

Comment: This is for moving data into a Data Warehouse on a recurring basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Postgres and CDC base replication a good option could be Debezium connectors.
Debezium has an Postgres and Oracle connector:

http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/oracle/
http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/

Comment: The Oracle connector is described as "incomplete"

Comment: What about this tools:

EDB:  Adappters from Postgres to anothrer databases (Postgres, mysql, hadoop)
https://www.enterprisedb.com/product/edb-postgres-platform/edb-postgres-data-adapters

JDBC and read the WAL:
https://github.com/davecramer/presentations/blob/master/JDBC%20Performance%20Scale%2015x.pdf
https://github.com/davecramer/LogicalDecode
https://github.com/confluentinc/bottledwater-pg  (i like this project but now it is unmaintained   :'( )

With Kafka:
http://debezium.io/

Wals as JSON
https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json

Answer (score 7):

There is no such feature at this time and the transaction logs lack some of the key information you would need to implement such a feature.

Work is ongoing for PostgreSQL 9.4 to implement [logical and bi-directional replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide) between PostgreSQL instances. Part of this work involves enhancements to the xlogs to add some key information required for logical row replication, adding a new `wal_level = 'logical'` option. There's also a *pluggable* infrastructure for decoding the WAL and streaming it to remote hosts, writing SQL to a file, etc.

That's where it becomes useful to you. Your best bet at this point is probably to use that infrastructure to decode PostgreSQL WAL into a change stream you can send to your remote Oracle or SQL Server systems. This will involve a considerable amount of development, as the logical replication code is somewhat immature and still has some limitations even with Postgresql-to-PostgreSQL limitations. DDL is totally unsupported at this time, for one thing.

If you do this you'll need to understand that the BDR work will probably *not* be committed into PostgreSQL 9.4 in a fully compatible form so you'd have to do re-work to make it compatible with main-line PostgreSQL later.

You'll want to start by adapting the existing text output plugin for the logical walsender to generate more database-agnostic SQL.

If this all sounds way too hard then your only other option is to implement a trigger-based replication solution or adapt an existing trigger based replication system to meet your needs. This will be much (*much*) higher overhead on the server, but a fair bit simpler.

*I should disclose that I work for [2ndQuadrant](http://2ndquadrant.com/), who're developing bidirectional replication for PostgreSQL, and I've recently started working on testing and documentation as part of the project.*

---

**Update as of 2014-07**: Logical changeset extraction / logical decoding was committed to PostgreSQL 9.4, and is due to be released soon. Beta 2 came out a few days ago.

See:

- [the 9.4 docs on logical decoding](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/logicaldecoding.html)
- [Robert Haas's post on the topic](http://rhaas.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/postgresql-now-has-logical-decoding.html)
- [depesz's post on the topic](http://www.depesz.com/2014/03/06/waiting-for-9-4-introduce-logical-decoding/)
- [Michael Paquier's post on the topic](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-basics-logical-decoding/)

Logical decoding makes it possible to implement what you want, but does not provide the feature you want directly. To stream changes into MS SQL, Oracle, etc, you would need an *output plugin* for logical decoding that can stream data to a streaming logical log receiver. The receiver application would maintain a connection to the target server and apply the changes as it receives them from PostgreSQL.

This is the basis of the PostgreSQL [BDR/UDR](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide) architecture. BDR is not directly useful for your purposes, but the logical changeset decoding feature that was built to make BDR possible will be.

A good starting point would be to look at the [`test_decoding` plugin](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/test-decoding.html)

Comment: @DavidCleaves See the above update for the current status and more detail. There's no canned out-of-the-box system to just pick up and use, but more of the infrastructure is there.

Comment: Fascinating @craigringer.  You might be interested in this Q http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159299/a-simple-solution-to-the-logical-decoding-sequence-problem-in-postgres .. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have made a python code for CDC logical replication (Postgres) that supports output plugins - test_decoding and pgoutput along with the decoder that works perfectly OK for me. Also I have done some formatting in decoded output of pgoutput to get the messages in JSON format for better usability.

Here is the link to the same - https://github.com/PhantomHunt/cdc_postgres_logical_replication

Pgoutput gives messages in encoded format and you have to decode it using algorithm specified here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/protocol-logicalrep-message-formats.html.

Kindly do let me know if you encounter any bugs or issues in this code.